# Why use parameters in function?

Tags: swift, parameters

I have been reading a lot of parameters in function but did not figure out why using parameters in swift is useful?

Code without parameter:

```
var name = "John"
func sayHello() -> String {
let greeting = "Hello, " + name + "!"
return greeting
}
print(sayHello()) // Hello, John!
```

Code with parameter:

```
func sayHello(name: String) -> String {
let greeting = "Hello, " + name + "!"
return greeting
}
print(sayHello("John")) //Hello, John!
```

Result is same.

Comment: Try using `sayHello()` with three different names without copying the whole function. Then you know why :)

Comment: Do you know what "scope" means?

Comment: simply because you do not want global variables!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters make your code more reusable. Without them, you would have to retype (copy) the code over and over everything you wanted to use it. In your example, you would have to recopy the code every time you wanted to say hello to another name. With parameters, you can simply recall the function with a different parameter. For a very simple program, you may not need them, but as your program grow more complex, however; you will need them or at least should consider using them.You also mentioned scope. Scope is, essentially, where a variable can be used. The two terms you should know dealing with scope are local and global. If you declare a variable at the start of the class it is said to be global. Global variables take up more space in memory because they take longer to become deallocated. If you declare it within a function or loop, it is said to be local to that structure. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

When you get into more advanced things you will need to carry certain parameters from one function to another. It is also a lot of preference. Some people prefer to code that way.

Same as the std:: in c++. Some people are just use to doing it